# Simple click handler to call method: SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Angular application running Jasmine on Karma for unit testing. I have provided a test to see if the method was called on the click event.

**Result: SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should call method on view item click**

Why isn't my expectation that the spy(method) has been called?

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="general-log-heading">
    <a class="btn btn-link onViewItemClick" (click)="onViewItem(searchResultItem)">test</a>
</h3>
```

**.TS**

```
public onViewItem(item: Results): void {
  //method logic here
}
```

**.spec(test)**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SearchResultItemComponent } from './search-result-item.component';

let component: SearchResultItemComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchResultItemComponent>;

fdescribe('SearchResultItemComponent', () => {


    beforeEach(() => {
        
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: []
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchResultItemComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });



    it('should call method on view item click', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.onViewItemClick'));
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'onViewItem');

    button.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    
});
})
```

**UPDATE to .spec** also tried

```
it('should should trigger a method on view item click', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
      const spy = spyOn(comp, 'onViewItem');
  
      let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.onViewItemClick')).nativeElement.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });


it('should should trigger a method on view item click', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

      let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
      const spy = spyOn(comp, 'onViewItem');
  
      let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.onViewItemClick')).nativeElement.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detectChanges is eagerly evaluated, no need to wait for `whenStable`.

```
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

also if you want to make async test you can return the promise that you want to w8t of, or you can use async await

```
fixture.detectChanges();
return fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

or

```
fixture.detectChanges();
await fixture.whenStable();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: All the above still gives me the message that there isnt any expectations. I have updated my .spec to show you the latest combo.

Comment: why are you still using whenStable()? if you do - then return it, as in my example, or await it

Comment: im not now at all.. still same issue :(

Comment: updated... the same but without the whenStable()

Comment: you can't get the same error withot any asynchroniosity in the test

Comment: Could you please tell me why do we need to return the fixture.whenStable() in order for it to work?